# Craft Commerce > 2.2: How can you order line items?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2, ecommerce

As of Commerce 2.2 line items are ordered by date created.

How can you order line items differently?

`{% for item in cart.lineItems.orderBy(’sku desc') %}` does not work…

Answer (score 3):

I am posting the answer of Craft Commerce Support in case somebody stumbles over the same thing:

It is possible to order them differently if required. The code example below shows how to order them alphabetically by SKU.

```
{% set lineItems = cart.lineItems|sort((a,  b) => a.sku <=> b.sku)  %}
<ul>
    {% for item in lineItems %}
        <li>{{ item.description }} - [{{ item.sku }}]</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Thanks Nathaniel